# Conversion Action for Android App isn't Created Automatically

Tags: android, google-ads-api

I have an Android app targets children. I want to create an app install campaign for it. But when i select it an conversion action for it isn't created automatically. And because app targets children i can't create a conversion action for it myself. I have multiple apps on Play Store. When i try it for them most of them are creates a conversion action automatically and some of them doesn't. Can you help?
https://imgur.com/gallery/4B4axkV